# Installation of Istio on GKE / Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have created a free account on GCP as also my first cluster.

I want to deploy `istio` on my GKE cluster, so I am following the [official instructions](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/install/platform/gke/).

At some point, the instructions indicate that I should

> Ensure that the Google Kubernetes Engine API is enabled for your
>   project (also found by navigating to “APIs & Services” -> “Dashboard”
>   in the navigation bar)

What is that supposed to mean?
Isn't the API already active since I have created and I am running a cluster?

How can a cluster be running **without** the API being enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling GKE API is the prerequisite for running GKE. If you already run GKE then you can skip this part.

You can enable Istio as a part of GKE cluster creation. Here is the good instruction from Google: https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing

Answer (score 0):

Those information how to install Istio on GKE - described "Istio instalation on GKE **add-on**".

If you are interested with the instructions how to install Istio manually you can find instructions from google [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/installing-istio).

To verify disable/enable API for GKE, please run:

**APIs & Services**

type:

**Kubernetes Engine API**

This overview provide more information about this api.